# I have problems converting debezium topic to mongodb timeseries

Tags: mongodb, apache-kafka, time-series, debezium

I have a PostgreSQL partitioned table -partitioned by timestamp field- which I want to replicate in MongoDB as a timeseries collecion. I have a source debezium connecor which reads all partitions of PostgreSQL table in one single kafka topic through debezium's reroute transform. I Have a sink connector which writes the mentioned topic in mongoDB. I have set Kafka Time Series Properties in connector configs to make the collection as a timeseries one, but it fails.

I think it is because of this: in [Time Series Collection Limitations](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/timeseries/timeseries-limitations/) it is mentioned that update command must not set upsert: true and debezium sets upsert: true. does anyone have a suggestion to solve this problem? thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

fortunately I managed to solve my problem. the main problem was that I was using "at.grahsl.kafka.connect.mongodb.MongoDbSinkConnector" as my connector class. when I changed it to "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSinkConnector", I could get a timeseries collection in mongodb using timeseries.timefield key (I used the docker image "confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect:5.3.0" to build my connect service which provides the mentioned connector class).

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).